# Inconsistent JSON

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to parse JSON in C# which is inconsistent, i.e
Below are the example of JSON that I am getting.

```
    {
    "Timestamp" : "2019-05-09T11:24:25.000Z",
    "Channel" : "web",
    "Supplier" : "kunde",
    "Generator" : "survey",
    "Type" : "hudtest",
    "Data" :{
        "Alder" : "20-29",
        "Køn" : "Kvinde",
        "Hudtype" : "sensitiv",
        "Hudtilstand" : "mixet"
       }
}
```

and variation of this JSON is like this:

```
    {
    "Timestamp" : "2019-05-09T11:24:25.000Z",
    "Channel" : "web",
    "Supplier" : "kunde",
    "Generator" : "survey",
    "Type" : "hudtest",
    "Data" :{
        "Alder" : "20-29",
        "Køn" : "Kvinde",
        "Hudtype" : "sensitiv",
        "Hudtilstand" : "mixet",
        "materialistID" : 61234,
        "Anbefalede produkter" : [ 100225, 725125 ]
    }
}
```

As you can see in both example I have different values in `Data` key. How can I parse this JSON in C#?

FYI: The `Data` key can have different value from the example i shared above. Not only `"Anbefalede produkter`. It can contain number of different values.
I have tried making it `dynamic` or parsing into `anonymous` type as well. But I also want to validate my JSON schema, Except `Data` Key other keys must be validated and they are mandatory.

Comment: So the difference is that there are optional fields? Most if not all JSON parsers will support that - you'll just end up with null Anbefalede produkter in the first case. Or do you want to parse the data into a dynamic object that will accept any values?

Comment: Is it actually different, or are there just empty properties sometimes?

Comment: One option would be to parse it into a `Dictionary<string, object>`. It depends on how dynamic the differences are.

Comment: Or you may create two seperate model to parse both the case. Or you may create just one model and add all the fields in each case the extra field will get a null value and while you using you can have the same check.

Comment: @HarshRaj I have no idea what parameters will be included in `Data` key. that's the issue for me. The `Data` key will have inconsistent values.

Comment: Make it `dynamic` then.

Comment: Ok but than i want to validate the my json as well, other than Data Key, other Keys has to be validated. How can i do it, if i make it `dynamic`?

Comment: Don't make it dynamic. Using a Dictionary<string, object> makes more sense than dynamic in almost every scenario

Comment: @JoePhillips Ok but how would I Validate my JSON, as I updated my question. I do need to validate my JSON as other keys except `Data` are mandatory.

Comment: @Shabirjan You want to do model validation? Do you have a model that you can share with us?

Comment: @JoePhillips No, that's where i am confused, how should I construct the model in which one of Key has inconsistent values.

Comment: @Shabirjan Are you using asp.net? It has model validation built in, otherwise you will probably want to look into System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator class

Comment: @JoePhillips I am using .net core. I am very new to C#, so if you can guide me, how can i validate my JSON. i.e if any of the keys i mentioned above are missing or contain null value, the parsing should fails

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194075/discussion-between-joe-phillips-and-shabir-jan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

```
      class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string jsonData = @"{  'Timestamp': '2019-05-09T11:24:25.000Z',
    'Channel': 'web',
    'Supplier': 'kunde',
    'Generator': 'survey',
    'Type': 'hudtest',
    'Data': {
        'Alder': '20-29',
        'Køn': 'Kvinde',
        'Hudtype': 'sensitiv',
        'Hudtilstand': 'mixet',
        'materialistID': 61234,
        'Anbefalede produkter': [100225, 725125]
    }
}";

            var b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonData);

            //Console.WriteLine(b.Data.Hudtype);
            //or
            Console.WriteLine(b.Data["Hudtype"]);

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

    }

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Channel { get; set; }
        public string Supplier { get; set; }
        public string Generator { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Hope this will solve your problem. 
Thanks

Comment: In order to validate you need to know the key names which are coming in Data.

Comment: Replace `dynamic` with `Dictionary<string, object>` and I'd agree with this. You can't rely on a model validator to understand this data. You need to validate it by hand because it is dynamic. If you want model validation to do all the work, don't allow dynamic data. Alternatively, you can use a base class or interface which only has the shared properties and validate against that

Comment: did the necessary changes as per your suggestion @JoePhillips

Comment: @JoePhillips Thanks for your input. So let say i have to validate only `TimeStamp`, `Channel`, `Supplier`, `Generator`, `Type` from my JSON schema, What will be the best way to do that. I am simply ignoring the `Data` as its the only part which contain dynamic content.